80s live-action short film with a labyrinth/elf/handprint/minotaur
Here’s what I know:

I saw it in the mid 80s so it’s at least that old.
I saw it at school during a class so it wasn’t full film-length.
It was definitely live action, and definitely color.
Storyline: a boy must find a new land for his people (elves, I think) to live in. He travels through a labyrinth, including a scene where a monster (Minotaur, I think) chases him across a stone walkway that is carrying him backward toward it. He reaches two huge stone doors to the promised land but they’ve already closed - he’s too late. Or is he? He places his hand on the handprint shape on the door… it glows green… the doors open and the promised land is revealed before him.
I think the boy might have been playing chess at the top of the labyrinth with an old man at the start, but I may be mixing that up with something else.
The worst thing is that I DID find this years ago, so I know it’s real, but the YouTube video of it that I had bookmarked has been taken down and the title no longer displays (and I didn’t write it down on a piece of paper anywhere), so now I’m trying to find it all over again. ;_;
What I learned last time I found it: turns out it was written by a famous sci-fi/fantasy author. (BTW I searched first on this forum in case this was where someone identified it last time, but nothing came up, so sadly it must have been on another site.)
What people always suggest, but it is none of these: Labyrinth, Dark Crystal, The Ray Bradbury Theater, Jim Henson’s Storytellers

Esoteric knowledge-holders, surely one of you must recognize this? My fingers are crossed.

Gozer the Gozerian, Gozer the Destructor, Volguus Zildrohar, the Traveller has come!

Ah, there’s nothing like a warm welcome. ☺️

I believe you are remembering QUEST by Elaine and Saul Bass (1984), a roughly twenty-minute film based on the story "Frost and Fire" by Ray Bradbury.
It takes place on another planet. It isn't a labyrinth but looks similar, it isn't a minotaur but looks similar, and it also isn't chess but appears similar. However, everything story-wise matches. Including the ending.
Here is a summary:

On a distant planet, descendants of a crashed spaceship are subjected to mysterious forces that cause them to age and die in just eight days. They must also live in caves to escape the bitter cold of night and the killing heat of day. One young boy is determined to find his way back to the ship that brought them there. But how will accomplish this in the short time left to him ?

From the summary on the YouTube upload here.
Here are screencaps:




Hah!  I remember being shown this in school, too. XD

Yes!!!!! Thank you thank you thank you. And it WAS by Ray Bradbury after all. I had been going into a spiral because I was so certain the author was Bradbury, but no matter how many times I read through the episode descriptions of Bradbury Theater, I couldn’t find it, and when I googled short films by Bradbury, that show was the only thing I could find. I was honestly starting to question my own memory. Ah, you brilliant wonderful human being! I cannot thank you enough.
Now to write this on a piece of paper and glue it to some physical location where I can never lose it again.
